# Confused about Vuex modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'll try and lay this out as cleanly as possible:

I have a Vue component that I'm rendering called World.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    This is the whole world
    <v-btn @click="test()" />
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('drawers', ['isEquipmentOpen']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('drawers', ['test']),
  },
};
</script>
```

And I have a module in for the Vuex store called drawers (drawers.js):

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    isEquipmentOpen: false,
  },
  actions: {
    test(state) {
      console.log(state.isEquipmentOpen);
      state.isEquipmentOpen = !state.isEquipmentOpen;
    },
  },
};
```

What I don't understand is why when test() is called, it can't access isEquipmentOpen (logs a value of `undefined`). How can I manipulate isEquipmentOpen?

Comment: The problem is that `state` is not a state but store context.

Comment: @EstusFlask See my comment on the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate state values from actions.

- You'll need to create a mutations property, create a setter method in it
  and call it in order to change the value.
- Pass a { commit } parameter to method in actions property.

You don't need to pass the state parameter in actions methods.
**Make sure that the string value in the commit() is the same as the setter name.**

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    isEquipmentOpen: false,
  },
  actions: {
    test({ commit }) {
      console.log(state.isEquipmentOpen);
      
      commit("setIsEquipmentOpen");
    },
  mutations: {
    setIsEquipmentOpen: state => state.isEquipmentOpen != state.isEquipmentOpen 
  },
};
```

Hope you understood the answer!

Comment: It's worth noting, that vuex `actions` get the store-context as first parameter, rather than the `state` which are the first parameter of `mutations` and `getters`. The `test({ commit }) { commit("someCommit") }` is the same as `test(store) { store.commit("someCommit") }`. It's just a shorthand usage of the property export. Same goes for `test({commit, dispatch, rootGetters })`

Comment: You can mutate inside actions. This hasn't been considered a good practice yet, but this is allowed. Notice that only actions but no mutations are expected in future Vuex versions.

Comment: @EstusFlask So the original approach could be written as `test(store) { store.state.isEqipmentOpen = !store.state.isEquipmentOpen; }`?

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, that can be done as well!